# Creating 4D Axes - Manim

Tags: python, axis, manim, 4d

I'm trying to achieve a way of showing 4d characteristics in manim. I would appreciate any way of showing a 4d axes and moving mobjects in a 4d way without coding the mathematics myself. is there a plugin for doing that?

Comment: How do you plan to visualize 4D on a 2D screen? Do you have any example of someone else succeeding in a convincing way that you want to duplicate/achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.